# Sublime Plugin Text Input

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I have been watching OdatNurd youtube plugin dev tutorials on gathering text.

I want to execute a command palette command via a mapped key

The json command file:

```json
[
  {
    "caption": "A sample command", 
    "command": "example", 
    "args": {
        // "message": "Sample",
        // "position": 0
    },
  },
]
```

Key mapping for my command

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+3"], "command": "example", "args": {"message": "1"}}
```

The issue I have is that I have 2 arguments in my sublime-command json file and I don't want to pass one of the values, but execution via the key mapped complains that the command wants 2 argument and I have passed 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: The key mapping is now not the issue.

Comment: The issue I have is that i have 2 arguments in my sublime-command json file and I don't want to pass one of the values, but execution the command via the key mapped complains that the command wants 2 argument and I have passed 1.

Comment: WIthout seeing what your implementation of the `example` command is, it's hard to say why this might be going wrong for you. A simple implementation such as the one outlined in the first of my videos that you referenced works just fine for me via the key binding without generating an error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which videos you're watching as you didn't include any links, but one option to try would be to use a `null` value for the option you don't want to send (for some reason?). For example:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+3"], "command": "example", "args": {"message": "1", "position": null}}
```

In Python, this translates to

```py
example(message="1", position=None)
```

I don't know the structure of your class `ExampleCommand`, so I don't know if it'll choke on the `null`/`None`, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I am watching you PT101-09 and 10.

Comment: I am watching your PT101-09 and 10 tuts. Your suggestion of the use of null as the position argument certainly returns None.  But I can't find a way to trap the value of None to force the ListInputHandler class to be invoked.

Comment: Can you please provide actual links to the videos? I didn't make them.

Comment: The links are: https://youtu.be/3UHIv7IP9kQ?list=PLGfKZJVuHW91zln4ADyZA3sxGEmq32Wse   and https://youtu.be/_LkrZB-J7kI?list=PLGfKZJVuHW91zln4ADyZA3sxGEmq32Wse

Comment: Just double-checking - is the `example` command available in the Command Palette? (https://youtu.be/3UHIv7IP9kQ?t=518)

Comment: I don't think I have explained the problem very well.  I have set up a command which I execute using the Sublime standard shift/command/p It uses textinputhandler and a listinputhandler. It, and the associated python plugin work fine using shit/cmd/p but if I set up my own keyboard mapping, I have to provide both arguments (the text and the list entry).  I can't find a way of triggering the listinputhandler when a value has been provided by the key mapping even if that value is None.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what might be going wrong for you because you haven't provided the example implementation of the command that you're using. I can come up with a likely scenario for what's going wrong based on the symptoms you've described however.

For the sake of clarity here (now and for anyone that hasn't watched the associated videos), here's an example of the plugin as it appears in the first of the videos you referenced, along with an associated command palette entry and key binding for it:

#### Plugin

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MessageInputHandler(sublime_plugin.TextInputHandler):
    def next_input(self, args):
        if 'position' not in args:
            return PositionInputHandler()


class PositionInputHandler(sublime_plugin.ListInputHandler):
    def list_items(self):
        return [
            ('Top of file', 0),
            ('Botto of file', -1)
        ]


class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, message, position):
        if position < 0:
            position = self.view.size()

        self.view.insert(edit, position, message)

    def input(self, args):
        if 'message' not in args:
            return MessageInputHandler()
        elif 'position' not in args:
            return PositionInputHandler()
```

#### Command palette entry

```json
    { "caption": "An example command", "command": "example" },
```

#### Key Binding

```json
    { "keys": ["ctrl+3"], "command": "example", "args": {
        "message": "1"
    }},
```

As defined here, the command takes two arguments, `message` that is some text to insert, and `position` that is the location to insert it at.

Since the `run` method declares that the command takes two arguments, in the normal state of affairs executing the command without providing both arguments will cause a Python error because arguments to commands are passed to `run()`, and without all of the arguments the call to the method is incorrect.

Using the `input()` method in conjunction with having the command in the command palette changes this behaviour; Internally Sublime will catch the error, notice that the command implements `input()` and then invoke it to see if it should be prompting the user via the Command Palette for any missing arguments.

The important parts here are that this will only happen if the command is in the command palette, and that the arguments that get prompted for are entirely under the control of the command itself, since Sublime can't make a general determination on what the missing arguments are supposed to represent.

Using the example of the plugin above, executing the command via the command palette entry has it ask you first for the text to insert, and then for the location in the list input handler.

Using the key binding also invokes the command, but now the prompt you get jumps directly to the `ListInputHandler` asking you where to do the insertion, skipping over the prompt for the text.

Why? Because the implementation of `input()` inspects the arguments that were provided, and only prompts you for `message` if the argument isn't given; since the key binding provides that argument, it skips to checking for the `position` argument, finds it missing, and prompts you for that instead.

Per your original question:

> The issue I have is that I have 2 arguments in my sublime-command json file and I don't want to pass one of the values, but execution via the key mapped complains that the command wants 2 argument and I have passed 1.

It's important first to note that regarding the entry in the command palette, the arguments presented there are only used when the command is actually executed via the command palette. When executed via the key binding, nothing about the command palette configuration is used (except that the entry has to exist).

So, all else being equal based on your original question, the key binding should work as expected so long as the `input()` method exists and knows to ask for the right arguments.

For example, if `input()` is not defined, then Sublime can't prompt you, and you get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tmartin/local/sublime_text_4101/Lib/python38/sublime_plugin.py", line 1512, in run_
    return self.run(edit, **args)
TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'position'
```

Or, if the `input()` method is defined but doesn't know that it should look for the missing argument and prompt you for it, that will also cause a problem:

```py
    def input(self, args):
        if 'message' not in args:
            return MessageInputHandler()
```

In this case the method is invoked, but since it's not looking to see if `position` is an argument that was missing, it falls off the bottom returning `None`, Sublime doesn't prompt you, and you get the same error as above.

In the comments above you also mentioned this:

> I don't think I have explained the problem very well. I have set up a command which I execute using the Sublime standard shift/command/p It uses textinputhandler and a listinputhandler. It, and the associated python plugin work fine using shit/cmd/p but if I set up my own keyboard mapping, I have to provide both arguments (the text and the list entry). I can't find a way of triggering the listinputhandler when a value has been provided by the key mapping even if that value is None

Again, without seeing the code it's hard to say with any exactness what might be happening. However, the fact that this works for you with that command palette entry (providing no arguments) but not from the key binding points to an issue with your `input()` method.

In particular, `input()` is called only once, and is expected to return an instance of an `InputHandler` for a specific argument. The input handler that `input()` returns is used to prompt for a specific argument, and when the user is done, the `next_input()` on the input handler is invoked to ask it "where do we go from here?"

As defined in the example plugin above and in the video, the `MessageInputHandler` responds to this by saying "if the `position` argument is also missing, ask for that next".

So, if this works from the command palette and not from the key binding, the most likely reason is that the `input` method is wrong; from the command palette having both items missing causes `input()` to ask for `message`, and `message` then asks for `position`, whereas from the key binding with `message` provided, `input()` must be returning `None`, stopping it from asking for `position` and causing your issue.

Comment: Resolved thank you, but the format of the json sublime-commands seemed to be the issue, which is puzzling.  Putting { "caption": "An example command", "command": "example" } on a single line seemed to be the resolution.

Comment: That change in whitespace is most certainly not important to the format; the file either loads or does not. If changing that fixed the problem you must also have changed something else at the same time.

Comment: I decided to get your example working first before dealing with my own code. I must have mistyped the command text.  I copied and pasted from your example above and it worked.  My code is also working now.  Thanks again.